# Magento-like Code Pools in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I really like the way that Magento uses code pools so that classes and functionality can be extended without actually changing the core functionality of the code.

(for those not familiar with Magento you can have the same class in the "core" code pool and the "local" code pool and when you create a class it first looks in the "local" code pool and if it does not exist it looks in the "core" code pool)

I know that Magneto uses the Zend Framework so I was wondering if Varien used something already inside of the Zend Framework of if they did this themselves? Or if someone knows if there is a good way to effectively do this in Zend Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know how Magento does that *(tipp: look at their sourcecode)*, but you could probably achieve the same with [`Zend_Autoloader`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html), e.g. when trying to load class `Foo_Bar_Baz` the autoloader will first look in `Local/Foo/Bar/Baz` and if the file isn't there it will try to load from `Core/Foo/Bar/Baz`.

---

> ***Note:*** If anyone's interested, take a look at the top of `app/Mage.php` (excerpt follows) to see how this gets set. --Alan

```
if (defined('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    $appPath = COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH;
    set_include_path($appPath . PS . Mage::registry('original_include_path'));
    include_once "Mage_Core_functions.php";
    include_once "Varien_Autoload.php";
} else {
    /**
     * Set include path
     */
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'local';
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'community';
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'app' . DS . 'code' . DS . 'core';
    $paths[] = BP . DS . 'lib';

    $appPath = implode(PS, $paths);
    set_include_path($appPath . PS . Mage::registry('original_include_path'));
    include_once "Mage/Core/functions.php";
    include_once "Varien/Autoload.php";
}
```

Comment: that's how it's done. it's nothing more than adding paths to the include path.